# Having problems with timer timings in 8051 assembly

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8051

I'm currently working on a school task that requires me to utilize timers to create 50% and 25% duty cycle waves from 8051s p2 ports. The 8051 is connected to a switch which is connected to P2.0. When switch=0, we have a 230Hz wave on p2.6 and a 460Hz wave on p2.7, both 50%. When switch=1, ports interchange frequencies, and waves reduce to 25%. I calculated the on and off times for both 50% and 25% and initialized reload values of TH/TL for each step (that I found suitable/necessary) but this did not result in the intended waveforms. Switch=0 case works flawlessly with an error less than %0.3 but the other case results in the waveforms below. The first image and second image come one after the other. I post them like this to increase understandability: [image: here]

[image: here]

I thought it had to do with either my code flow or my timer initializations but I couldn't find the source of error. I will provide the code below:

```
ORG 0

    SETUP:
        ;both timers set as mode 1 (16-bit counter)
        MOV TMOD, #11H

    MAIN:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JC MODE1

    MODE0:
        ; This part corresponds to switch = 0. F2 gets timer 1, F1 gets timer 0

        ;initialize timer 0
        MOV TL0, #0FAH
        MOV TH0, #0F7H
        SETB TR0

        ;initialize timer 1
        MOV TL1, #17H
        MOV TH1, #0FCH
        SETB TR1

    LOOPM0:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JC MODE1
        JB TF0, TIMER0
        JB TF1, TIMER1
        SJMP LOOPM0

    TIMER0:
        CPL P2.6
        ;Reset timer 0
        CLR TF0
        MOV TL0, #0FAH
        MOV TH0, #0F7H

        SJMP LOOPM0

    TIMER1:
        CPL P2.7
        ;Reset timer 1
        CLR TF1
        MOV TL1, #17H
        MOV TH1, #0FCH

        SJMP LOOPM0

    MODE1:
        CLR TF1
        CLR TF0
        ; This part corresponds to switch =1, F1 gets timer 1, F2 gets timer 0
        ;Setup for OFF1, F2

        ;TH0/TL0 = FA21
        MOV TL0, #21H
        MOV TH0, #0FAH
        SETB TR0

        ;Setup for OFF1, F1
        ;TH1/TL1 = FD10
        MOV TL1, #11H
        MOV TH1, #0FDH
        SETB TR1

    LOOPM1:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JNC MODE0
        JB TF0, STIMER0
        JB TF1, STIMER1
        SJMP LOOPM1

    STIMER0:
        CPL P2.7
        CLR TF0

        ;TH0/TL0 = FC17
        MOV TL0, #17H
        MOV TH0, #0FCH

        SJMP LOOPM2
    STIMER1:
        CPL P2.6
        CLR TF1

        ;TH1/TL1 = FE0B
        MOV TL1, #0BH
        MOV TH1, #0FEH

        SJMP LOOPM2


    LOOPM2:
        MOV C, P2.0
        JNC MODE0
        JB TF0, STIMER00
        JB TF1, STIMER11
        SJMP LOOPM2

    STIMER00:
        CPL P2.7
        CLR TF0
        ;TH0/TL0 = FA21
        MOV TL0, #21H
        MOV TH0, #0FAH
        SJMP LOOPM1

    STIMER11:
        CPL P2.6
        CLR TF1
        ;TH1/TL1 = FD12
        MOV TL1, #11H
        MOV TH1, #0FDH
        SJMP LOOPM1



END
```

P.S. I would be very happy if you could just state my error and give small suggestions, rather than correcting the whole code since I want to try and learn from my mistakes.

Comment: What I would do is just use a single timer with time base for 460Hz*4 and sequence both inputs from a counter that resets after 8 steps. The faster signal would be on for the first cycle, the slower for the first two.

Comment: In the first case, you have one loop for creating a signal. In the second case, you have two loops. The problem is that you are testing two timers in both loops. If any of them expires, you go to the second loop where you generate other times. But for the longer lasting time, the time from the original first loop and not from the second should still apply.
This algorithm is fundamentally wrong and another one must be invented.